# java.sql.Timestamp created from java.util.Date, why always before() it?

Tags: java, time

Following a bug, I've noticed that if I create a java.sql.Timestamp from a java.util.Date, using the constructor that takes the milliseconds, the Date instance is always after() the Timestamp. This is puzzling, since (a) the contract for before() specifies a strict comparison and (b) if not equal, the Timestamp, because it has nanoseconds, might itself be after() the Date. But the results are opposite and repeatable (with JDK 1.6 and 1.7, with different JVM timezones). Comparing two Dates works correctly, but calling before() or after() on a Date and giving a Timestamp argument has unexpected results.

The sample code below has two Date and one Timestamp instance, all of them with the same millisecond value. Yet comparing a Date with a Timestamp shows the Date to be after() the Timestamp.

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.sql.Timestamp;

public class X extends Date {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Date d1 = new Date();
        Date d2 = new Date(d1.getTime());
        Timestamp t = new Timestamp (d1.getTime());
        System.out.println ("date1 = " + d1 + " (" + d1.getTime() + ")" );
        System.out.println ("date2 = " + d2 + " (" + d2.getTime() + ")" );
        System.out.println ("timestamp = " + t + "  (" + t.getTime() + ")" );
        System.out.println ("d1 before d2: " + d1.before(d2));
        System.out.println ("d1 after  d2: " + d1.after(d2));
        System.out.println ("d1 before ts: " + d1.before(t));
        System.out.println ("d1 after  ts: " + d1.after(t)); //why true?
    }
}
```

Sample output:

```
C:\>\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\bin\java X
date1 = Tue Oct 30 10:15:59 EDT 2012 (1351606559812)
date2 = Tue Oct 30 10:15:59 EDT 2012 (1351606559812)
timestamp = 2012-10-30 10:15:59.812  (1351606559812)
d1 before d2: false
d1 after  d2: false
d1 before ts: false
d1 after  ts: true
```

The last line is the curious one.

Thank you.

Comment: Use the debugger to point that out. And remind the [Timestamp API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) *"[...] it is recommended that code not view Timestamp values generically as an instance of java.util.Date."*

Comment: `d1.compareTo(ts);` results `1`, indicating there is a 1 nano difference or something of the likes. ___ I believe it's a bug, yes. Nice job finding it!

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look at the internal representation and what is compared in the `after()` method, you see that for example for

```
millis = 1351607849957
```

you get a `Date` with

```
fastTime = 1351607849957
```

and  a `Timestamp` with

```
fastTime = 1351607849000
nanos = 957000000
```

Since all that is compared is the `fastTime` part, you get your observed behaviour.
As @user714965 points out above, you aren't supposed to treat a `Timestamp` as a `Date`.

Answer (score 4):

The API documentation of `java.sql.Timestamp` says:

> **Note:** This type is a composite of a `java.util.Date` and a separate nanoseconds value. Only integral seconds are stored in the `java.util.Date` component. The fractional seconds - the nanos - are separate.

(That agrees with Keppil's answer).

It also says:

> Due to the differences between the `Timestamp` class and the `java.util.Date` class mentioned above, it is recommended that code not view `Timestamp` values generically as an instance of `java.util.Date`. The inheritance relationship between `Timestamp` and `java.util.Date` really denotes implementation inheritance, and not type inheritance.

That means you should not treat `Timestamp` as a `java.util.Date`, which is what you are doing if you pass it to `java.util.Date.after()` (that method expects a `java.util.Date` - you're passing in a `Timestamp`, treating it as if it's a `java.util.Date`, which this comment says you shouldn't do).

This is ofcourse bad design in the standard Java library. If you need to work with dates and times, use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/), a much better designed and more powerful library.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of those differences (and incompatibilities, particularly in equals()) as well as Joda, but I'm looking for an explanation of this odd behaviour.

Comment: Note that you can dig into the source code of a class such as `java.sql.Timestamp`, you can find it in the file `src.zip` which is in your JDK installation directory.